# What is the callgraph expansion stage in g++?

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, profiling

I am profiling my program;s compilation and looking for bottlenecks. I originally thought template instantiation would be the most expensive part but seems to be callgraph funciton expansion. Problem is, I have no idea what that stage refers to.

```
callgraph functions expansion      :  28.98 ( 80%)   0.95 ( 39%)  29.98 ( 73%)   782M ( 60%)
 template instantiation             :   2.36 (  7%)   0.47 ( 19%)   2.84 (  7%)   191M ( 15%)
```

I have tried to search it up online but I find no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be part of the optimization process implemented by GCC. I was able to find one reference, [The GCC call graph module](http://www.netgull.com/gcc/summit/2004/GCC%20Call%20Graph.pdf), which describes it as the final step performed by the front-end of the compiler:

> 4. Expansion: We proceed in reverse DFS order on functions that are still present in the call-graph, applying inter-procedural optimizations such as inlining to the functions, and finally leaving them to the back-end to do the actual optimization and compilation.